# Responsive Table Containing Images

Tags: html, css, image, html-table, responsive-design

I am new to html and css and am trying to make a responsive table with images. Right now the table looks like this but scales down as the website page gets smaller, and does not branch into a new row:

```
+---------------------------------------+ 
| image A | image B | image C | image D | 
+---------------------------------------+
```

I am trying to get the table to split into a new row to look like this after the webpage gets to 700px:

```
+-------------------+
| image A | image B | 
+-------------------+
| image C | image D | 
+-------------------+
```

Comment: Do you have your heart set on using a table? This is super easy if you just put the images in a <div>.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show HTML code... And learn how to make: [mre]